# When do rails url generators accept an id versus an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Based on this [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), it seems that rails URL generators accept a full object to generate a URL.

```
@comment = Comment.find(1)
comment_url(@comment, { host: 'google.com' } ) => google.com/comments/1
```

This is true in my production environment. However in my dev environment, when I try to generate a URL this way I get a

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches / missing required keys: [:id]

error.

In my dev environment, I can successfully generate a url using the id of the object instead.

```
comment_url(@comment.id, { host: 'google.com' } ) => google.com/comments/1
```

It seems to me that **based on a config somewhere, you must be able to pass either objects or ids into URL generators in rails**. My google foo has failed me in figuring out what this config might be. Does anyone know why I might see this different behaviour in production versus dev of the same app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no difference in that talking about environments, it doesn't matter if you do that on production or development.

the only thing that is different there is the data, maybe the @comment on development isn't filled with an object that have an ID so it doesn't work on that example.

Comment: I think there must be a difference in the configs between the two environments. @comment on development does have an id. (Grabbed by using `@comment = Comment.find(1)`. My question is getting at - what type of configs exist that change the method signature of url generators in rails?

Comment: It turned out that the to_param method had been overwritten in the @comment model, to serialize a  hash_id attribute. That attribute was present in production but not dev. Thanks for that answer, it sent me down the right path.